# Windows Forms used by WPF does not have default system design

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

For instance if a "System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox" is created in a WPF application the design of buttons and such does not have default system appearance. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Are you talking about in the designer or when it runs? If it's the former then this is normal and I'm not aware of any solution. If it's the latter then I've not heard of this, have you at least got information such as what OS you're on and some code/screenshots?

Comment: I am talking about when it runs. And it it only when running Windows Forms under WPF. I've edited the question accordingly. I have tested under Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense now you've edited it. Glad it works :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. First add following first in main:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```

Then add manifest file and uncomment followning lines:

```
<!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->
   <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
          version="6.0.0.0"
          processorArchitecture="*"
          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
          language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
```

Now the Windows Forms used in the WPF application should have default appearance.